# how to use IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup?

Tags: sharepoint-server

i want to check in my code if the registered user be in a specific group . When i use `IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup` like this :

```
SPUser e = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser;
using (SPSite userContextSite = new SPSite("Web URL", e.UserToken))
{
    using (SPWeb userContextWeb = userContextSite.OpenWeb())
    {
        if(userContextWeb.IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(SPContext.Current.Web.SiteGroups["Dammak Hayah Members"].ID))
    }
}
```

> error : Group cannot be found.

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint seems to throw a “Group not found” error if the user is not a member of the group.

Hence use the try-catch:

```
private bool IsMemberOf(string groupName)
{
    SPUser user = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser;

    try
    {
        if (user.Groups[groupName] != null)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Call as:

```
IsMemberOf("group name here");
```

Reference: http://chris.gg/2010/02/how-to-check-whether-a-sharepoint-user-is-in-a-particular-group/

**OR** You can try this code:

```
private bool IsMemberOf(string groupName)
{
SPUser user = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser;
SPGroup group = SPContext.Current.Web.Groups[groupName];

return group.Users.GetCollection(new string[] { user.LoginName }).Count > 0;

}
```

Comment: i tried this but i think i have a problem with group name 
SPGroup group = web.SiteGroups["Dammak Hayah Owners"];

Comment: i got the group name from : site settings-->people and groups --> and take the name of group from the left side

Comment: is the user member of this group? SharePoint seems to throw a “Group not found” error if the user is not a member of the group.

Comment: yes the user is member in group

Answer (score 1):

```
SPWeb site = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPGroup Groupname = site.Groups["your group name"];
bool isexist = site.IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(Groupname);
```

Comment: i do this but the same error group cannot be found

Comment: i think i have problem with group name .. please tell me from where take the group name 
and thank you for help

Comment: have you tried with other group names?

Comment: yes tried with other group

Comment: its working for other groups?

Comment: no doesn't work

Comment: try with my updated ans

Comment: if it helped you than please upvote and mark it as an asnwer :)

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you

```
SPUser User = oWeb.EnsureUser(LoginName);
var spGroup = oWeb.Groups[GroupName];    
isResult = oWeb.IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(spGroup.ID);
```